# how to create an app "save file in app but no access another app to my file"?

Tags: java, android, file

I have the code below:

```
  InputStream input=null;
        OutputStream output=null;
        HttpURLConnection connection=null;
        try{
            URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
            connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            int filelen=connection.getContentLength();
            input=connection.getInputStream();
            filechache();
            output=new FileOutputStream(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/nikandroid/"
                    +strings[1]+".mp3");
            byte data[]=new byte[4096];
            long total=0;
            int count;
            while((count=input.read(data))!=-1){
                total+=count;
                if (filelen>0) publishProgress((int)(total*100/filelen));
                output.write(data,0,count);
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try{
                if (output!=null) output.close();
                if (input!=null) input.close();

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (connection!=null) connection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: store it in a object-DB of your application or crypt the file if not used.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: store it in a database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every application has a private directory in the internal storage. Contents of this directory can only be read and written by the app. The directory is

```
/data/data/<yourPackageName>
```

You can access various specialized directories within your app's directory like this:

- `context.getFilesDir()` returns `/data/data/<yourPackageName>/files`
- `context.getCacheDir()` returns `/data/data/<yourPackageName>/cache`

There may be similar directories on external/shared internal storage but that's beyond the scope of the question.